# How to create row/column selection matrix from a binary vector?

Tags: matrices, vectors

Given $n \leq m$, let $A$ be a matrix of shape $(n, m)$, and $x$ be a binary vector of length $m$ (it's guaranteed that there are exactly $n$ 1's in $x$). People could extract the columns of $A$ according to the positions of 1's in $x$ to form a new square matrix $B$ of shape $(n, n)$. For instance, if $n = 1$, $m = 2$, $A = \begin{bmatrix} 10 & 20 \end{bmatrix}$, and $x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, the desired selection matrix $S$ would then be $S = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \ 0\end{bmatrix}$ such that $AS = \begin{bmatrix} 10 \end{bmatrix}$. The first column of $A$ has been selected since the first entry of $x$ is 1.

The question is how to construct the selection matrix $S$ using only matrix multiplication and the Kronecker product of $x$ and some other well-known matrix, i.e., $S=f(x)$ where $f$ only involves matrix multiplication and the Kronecker product. One idea is to use an outer product trick, but there's no complete solution readily available. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\a{{\bar a}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}  \def\mt{\mapsto}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c|c}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$Suppose $(n,m)=(2,4).\;$ Then the binary vector will look something like $$x=\m{1&0&0&1}\in\R{m}$$

Using the all-ones matrix $\o\in\R{n}$ and the Hadamard product $(\odot)$ will get you
$$ A\odot \o x^T = \m{\a_1&0&0&\a_4} \in \R{m\times n} \qquad $$
Now you need some **algebraic** way of dropping the zero columns.